# calling post request method between two routes

Tags: javascript, express, google-api

I am trying to append data to google spreadsheet as part of a project I am working on. The main goal is to trigger a post method when submitting an HTML form to the server side. 
It redirects the call to a route called signMe.js which supposed forward the post request to a method within googlesheet.js which holds regenerated access token from google in case one was already expired.

Experiencing recent CORS issues, I decided to try the API approach, as this seems to be more elegant, however, so far I haven't figured out how to implement it correctly.

The HTML file contains the following:

```
<body style="background:#000;">

<form id="form" target="_self" method="POST" action="/signMe" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="deviceId" name="bID" placeholder="device id" type="text" required>
    <input id="usernameField" name="Username" placeholder="username" type="text" required>
    <input id="emailField" name="Email" placeholder="email" type="email" required>
    <input id="passwordField" name="Password" placeholder="password" type="password" required>
    <input id="phoneField" name="Phone" placeholder="phone" type="tel" pattern="^([+]|[00]{2})([0-9]|[ -])*"
        required>
    <button id="send" type="submit" class="common_btn">Register Now</button>
</form>

    <h3 id="success-msg" style="text-align: center !important; margin-top:190px !important; display:none; color:#fff">
        Your Request has been posted to Google Spreadsheet</h3>
</body>
```

signMe.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const helpers = require('./googlesheet');

    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});


    router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res, next) {

        var bID = req.body.bID;
        var Username = req.body.Username;
        var Email = req.body.Email;
        var Password = req.body.Password;
        var Phone = req.body.Phone;
        const tryGoogleSheets = async () => {
            await helpers.append('*Google Sheet ID*', 'users!A:Z', [ [bID, Username,Email,Password,Phone] ]);
        };
        res.json({msg: ""});
    });

module.exports = router;
```

googlesheet.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const _ = require('lodash');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const { google } = require('googleapis');

  const credentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('credentials.json', 'utf-8'));

  const {
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    client_id: clientId,
    redirect_uris: redirectUris,
  } = credentials.installed;

  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    clientId, clientSecret, redirectUris[0],
  );

  const token = fs.readFileSync('token.json', 'utf-8');
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));


    /**
   * Append content to the next line of a spreadsheet on specified range.
   * @param {string} spreadsheetId
   * @param {string} range
   * @returns {Promise}
   */
exports.append = async (spreadsheetId, range, values) => {
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: this.oAuth2Client });

    return sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      spreadsheetId,
      range,
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      resource: { values },
    });
  }
```

Please advise on how to proceed from here.

Comment: It looks like your code never actually calls `tryGoogleSheets()`.

Comment: Also, in googleSheet.js, the reference to `this.oAuth2Client` does not look correct.  It looks like `oAuth2Client` is a regular variable.

Comment: I am missing something here. How shall I invoke it then if not for calling signMe.js from the html table.

Comment: Inside of `signMe.js`, you define `const tryGoogleSheets = async () => {...}`, but you never call the function you defined.  You need to call it as in `tryGoogleSheets()`.  I don't know why you're wrapping it in an `async` function here in the first place as it does nothing useful for you.

Comment: Did you get it to work by calling `tryGoogleSheets()`?